# let different programs use different sound cards on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sound-card

I have a machine with 2 sound-cards. I would like to map an application to one sound-card and map a different application to the other sound-card. Is it possible on Windows 7? Is there any tool that can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From searching around it seems that this feature is solely dependent on the programs that you are using. Windows will choose one of the sound cards as the 'default', and many programs will use the default sound card.

However, some programs will allow you to set the default output. Below is an example showing how, when I have my headphones plugged in, Skype allows me to choose between my speakers and the headphones. I don't have two sound cards to test this with, but I would assume that you would be able to choose between the two cards.

[image: Skype options]